# Standard notation/symbol for an embedding function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, notation

Hello everyone,

Suppose that I am defining a function which embeds a surface (manifold) in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Is there a standard symbol or letter that is used for this function?

Additionally, is there any other classical or standard notation (such as the hooked arrow for inclusion maps) of which I ought to be aware?

Regards,

Christopher

Comment: Most embeddings I've met were called a lower case Roman letter between $e$ and $k$. As far as arrows, I prefer $\hookrightarrow$ for an embedding and $\looparrowright$ for an immersion, but you sometimes also see $\subset$ for an embedding and $\subseteq$ for an immersion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually use $\iota$ (\iota) for all kinds of embeddings.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is none.

Comment: Thanks Dox, I hadn't run into anything obviously standard in the literature, but I wanted to ask before I put it in my thesis!

Comment: You're welcome! (even if mine contribution was useless) 